# Missing Keyword (ORA-00905) - Oracle SQL Case Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case, ora-00905

Good morning,

I was wondering if one of you could help me - should be fairly quick I'd imagine; I'm a newbie so prone to missing obvious things.

I have the below statement which is returning the aforementioned 905 error...any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

```
(CASE CONTACTS.TELEPHONE_NO_DAY
    WHEN CONTACTS.TELEPHONE_NO_DAY LIKE '07%'
    THEN CONTACTS.TELEPHONE_NO_DAY
    ELSE NULL
    END) TEL_DAY,
   (CASE CONTACTS.TELEPHONE_NO_EVE
    WHEN CONTACTS.TELEPHONE_NO_EVE LIKE '07%'
    THEN CONTACTS.TELEPHONE_NO_EVE
    ELSE NULL
    END) TEL_EVE
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're mixing up two ways of doing case. You either need:

```
CASE <expression>
WHEN <comparison expression> THEN <return expression>
...
```

or

```
CASE
WHEN <condition> THEN <return expression>
...
```

These are the 'simple' and 'searched' variants in [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/expressions004.htm).

But as you can't use `like` in the first version, you need the second:

```
CASE
WHEN CONTACTS.TELEPHONE_NO_DAY LIKE '07%'
THEN CONTACTS.TELEPHONE_NO_DAY
ELSE NULL
END
```

You also don't need the brackets around the two `case` statements.