# Oracle SQL: Select with variable and condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm creating a query with a condition depending on the result of a variable.

- If PROD = 'alpha' I need to show only models 2,3,4,5 and 6;
- if PROD = 'beta' that only models 0 and 1 appear.

---

```
DEFINE PROD = 'ALPHA'

SELECT CAR_CODE, CAR, MODELS
FROM TB_CAR_MODELS
WHERE (
CASE PROD
WHEN 'ALPHA' THEN MODELS IN (2,3,4,5,6)
WHEN 'BETA' THEN MODELS IN (0,1)
END
);
```

I created this query but it's not working. Returns the error:

> 905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"

Can you help me please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few sample rows:

```
SQL> select * from tb_car_models;

  CAR_CODE CAR      MODELS
---------- ---- ----------
         1 BMW           2  -- ALPHA
         2 Audi          5  -- ALPHA
         3 Opel          0  -- BETA

SQL>
```

As I'm running it in SQL*Plus, I'm using a substitution variable:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from tb_car_models
  3  where models in (select models
  4                   from tb_car_models
  5                   where models in (2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
  6                     and '&&prod' = 'ALPHA'
  7                   union all
  8                   select models
  9                   from tb_car_models
 10                   where models in (0, 1)
 11                     and '&&prod' = 'BETA'
 12                  );
Enter value for prod: ALPHA

  CAR_CODE CAR      MODELS
---------- ---- ----------
         1 BMW           2
         2 Audi          5

SQL> undefine prod
SQL> /
Enter value for prod: BETA

  CAR_CODE CAR      MODELS
---------- ---- ----------
         3 Opel          0

SQL>
```

Depending on tool you use, that might be e.g. `... and :prod = 'ALPHA'` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good answer here that I think will help you:
[Missing Keyword (ORA-00905) - Oracle SQL Case Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12580026/missing-keyword-ora-00905-oracle-sql-case-statement)

Check that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your sql statement as following:

```
SELECT CAR_CODE, CAR,
(CASE S.PROD
WHEN CASE S.PROD = 'ALPHA' THEN MODELS IN (2,3,4,5,6)
WHEN  CASE S.PROD =  'BETA' THEN MODELS IN (0,1)
END
)  MODELS
FROM TB_CAR_MODELS S
```